How to come up with the idea for solving this problem: $x + \frac{1}{y} = 4, y + \frac{1}{z} = 1, \text{and} , z + \frac{1}{x} = \frac{7}{3}, xyz=?$
Here is the 2000 AMC 12, Problem 20:

If $x,y,$ and $z$ are positive numbers satisfying
$$x + \frac{1}{y} = 4,\qquad y + \frac{1}{z} = 1, \qquad \text{and}
 \qquad z + \frac{1}{x} = \frac{7}{3}$$ Then what is the value of $xyz$
?
$\text {(A)}\ \frac{2}{3} \qquad \text {(B)}\ 1 \qquad \text {(C)}\ \frac{4}{3} \qquad \text {(D)}\ 2 \qquad \text {(E)}\ \frac{7}{3}$

To solve this problem we multiply left-side of each equation together and their right-sides together and as the result we get,
$$xyz+x+y+z+\frac1x+\frac1y+\frac1z+\frac1{xyz}=\frac{28}3$$And it is equal to the sum of LHS of the three original equations plus $xyz+\frac1{xyz}$ from here it is easy to find $xyz$.
I'm wondering how would anyone come up with the idea of multiplying as I couldn't recognize it when I encountered this problem. The expression resulted from multiplication is not obvious to see beforehand.

Well, it's obvious that it will have an $xyz$ and a $\frac1{xyz}$ term, so it's tempting to go ahead and see what else we get.

I personally call this technique "There isn't much that we can do, so let's just try whatever we can and hope it leads to some further observation". It's not just wishful thinking, but more like very wishful thinking. Even though there's Misha's motivation of "Oh we can force out an $xyz$ term", but it's also not that clear that we have no further issues.

FWIW Apart from this elegant solution, there's also the brute force approach of using the first two equations to show that $  z = (x-4)/(x-3)$, substitute into the third and we get $ x = 3/2$, from which we can determine $y, z$. To me, that's the much more likely solution that people came up with, and it's what I would have done instead of hoping for a magical observation.

I suspect this is the first thing I would try, but only because it's an obvious way to get $xyz$ to show up and from prior experience with "multiplicative niceties" arising when expanding $\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2,$ $\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^3,$ etc. I suspect a more insightful explanation can be based on some kind of multiplicative analogue of what one does with linear cyclic equations (e.g. $x+y=1$ & $y+z=3$ & $z+x=6$ -- adding the equations leads to $x+y+z=5,$ then subtract each of the $3$ equations from $x+y+z=5),$ but I can't think of anything specific right now.

Does this help: $(4 - 1) \times \frac{7}{3} = 7$?

We'll yes that is one of the most efficient methods, but this can be done too, because the individual equations aren't that hard to solve
$$\text{Multiply the second equation by $\frac 1y =4-x$}$$
We get $$\frac{1}{yz}=3-x\implies \frac{1}{xyz}=\frac 3x -1$$
$$\text{Similarly we get $\frac{1}{xyz}=\frac{4}{3y}-\frac 73 $ using first and third eqn.}$$
$$\text{But $\frac{4}{3y}=\frac{16}{3}-\frac{4x}{3}$ }$$
So
$$\frac{1}{xyz}=\frac 3x -1 =3-\frac {4x}{3}\\\implies 4x^2-12x+9=0\implies x=\frac 32$$
$$\therefore \frac{1}{xyz}=1$$
